# Sharepoint unique permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

Today I had an incident where my manager was complaining that someone had access to one of the folder that was confidential. I told him that whenever a site is created, the folders that are created will inherit the root permissions and when someone is added to the root, they will be able to access the folder as well. The way to fix this is by stop inheriting permissions and remove users and add the necessary users for the folder. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be correct unless they're accessing it via a Shared Link; if using a Shared Link, then you'd need to delete that link from Manage Access on that content.

But start with disabling permission inheritance and removing that specific individual's access.

Comment: If the user wants to break inheritance, does he needs to have special permissions or owner permissions is sufficient? I’m confused.

Comment: Needs to have Full Control over the item to break inheritance.